# UWP XAML CommandBar Styling

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm looking to create an effect similar to how to CommandBar looks in the default Photos application.

[image: a busy cat]

I can get the bar to show easily enough but I'm struggling with three things:

- Making the labels of the buttons appear to the right and now below.
- Making the more button at the end show a dropdown and not expand / collapse the CommandBar itself.
- Trying to find out the height of the CommandBar so I can use Margin to set things below it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretty much everything you mention / need is [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) amigo, as for the margin you shouldn't need it if you just plop the `CommandBar` inside of `<Page.TopAppBar></Page.TopAppBar>`

Comment: I have been searching for over an hour and haven't come across that page but yes it all seems to be on there so thanks!